# EPROTO error on google action verification

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

I am working on an action on google using Actions SDK, however when i enabled the Actions; verification as described at:

https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/verify-requests

I am getting the below error, this only comes when i am behind corporate proxy, can anyone suggest a solution for this?

> {
>       "error": "ID token verification failed: Error: Failed to retrieve verification certificates: Error: write EPROTO 139904972138304:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:825:\n\n    at OAuth2Client. (/opt/app/node_modules/actions-on-google/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js:580:31)\n    at step (/opt/app/node_modules/actions-on-google/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js:57:23)\n    at Object.throw (/opt/app/node_modules/actions-on-google/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js:38:53)\n    at rejected (/opt/app/node_modules/actions-on-google/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js:30:65)\n    at propagateAslWrapper (/opt/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/ca-apm-probe/node_modules/async-listener/index.js:502:23)\n    at /opt/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/ca-apm-probe/node_modules/async-listener/glue.js:188:31\n    at /opt/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/ca-apm-probe/node_modules/async-listener/index.js:539:70\n    at /opt/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/ca-apm-probe/node_modules/async-listener/glue.js:188:31\n    at :null:null\n"
>   }

I am using v2.5.0 of actions-on-google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i was able to sort this issue, the underlying issue is with axios library being used by google auth library (v1.3.2)

here is the issue : https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/662

The workaround for me was to replace axios with request promise in google auth library and then publish it in our private npm registry, this solved the issue for now.